# React basic UseEffect question and dependency arrays

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I want to write the equivalent of componentDidMount so the docs tell me to use an emptyArray

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.myProp1)
    console.log(props.myProp2)

    console.log('DIDMOUNT.');
}, [])
```

But everytime I try to access a variable that is not part of the dependency array inside the useEffect callback, the warning is:

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'props.myProp1' and
> 'props.myProp2'.   Either include them or remove the dependency array
> react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Which defeats the purpose of having an empty-array (to simulate componentDidMount) ?

With Classes I simply write

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(props.myProp1)
    console.log(props.myProp2)
}
```

, and can access any variable that the Class is aware of;

**UPDATED:** I voted to close the question, as a comment below pointed to a duplicate.

Comment: The argument is that if you want to do something with `myProp1`, if that changes, you should want to do something different with it when it changes. Whether the rule *should* be ignored or not depends on what you're actually trying to do with those props.

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook

Comment: @Andrej, wow the way I read the answer is that I have to actually disable the ruling, Seriously, I didn't have to disable any rules with Class components just to log a variable

Comment: Then you need to fill in an issue with react developers. It is a known behavior of useEffect.

Comment: Ok Thank you Andrej for pointing to the existing answer.